# How to upload block to azure file storage using sas url?

Tags: azure, rest, file-upload, azure-blob-storage, shared-access-signatures

So, I managed to successfully generate a sas url for my blob and I can verify writing to the blob directly using the sas url. `PUT` request using Header: `x-ms-blob-type: BlockBlob`

Now I want to use the sas url to upload file blocks instead of uploading the entire file in a single request. I plan on later sending an append call to merge all the blocks together and make my file.
How can I achieve this using sas url? This is required because I want an external client to upload their file to our azure blob storage in a multipart form.

Comment: Please edit your question and include the code you have written for creating the blob in single request.

Comment: Any luck with this? I'm in the same boat as you

Comment: @Nihir I found the solution

Comment: I made some progress and discovered that I had to upload the file as a blob instead of a base64 string. But I haven't been able to get it working for multipart forms yet. How were you able to solve the issue?